# In case we have an interface written in a seperate .sol file how do we migrate it successfully?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, interfaces

HI consider i have 3 smart contracts A,B,C.
I have a separate file D.sol which is an interface used in all A,B and C.
What would the migration script look like for this project?

Answer (score 1):

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract D {
    function doit() returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "./D.sol";

contract A {
    D d = new D();

```
function dothat() returns (bool) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Try like this,it should work.

Comment: i only need the migration script for the project in javascript